# Xpath to extract data from a table using contains

Tags: xpath

Following 2 xpaths below work fine to extract data from a table.

```
//*[@id="codeRow"]/td/strong[contains(text(),"Besnier")] 
//*[@id="codeRow"]/td[contains(text(),"Besnier")]
```

I want to combine these 2 and create 1 XPATH statement that can be used as needed.
I tried using or but it did not work
ForEx:

```
    //*[@id="codeRow"]/td[contains(descendant::*/text() , "Besnier" )] 
 or [contains(text(),"Besnier")]
```

Please advise

Comment: There is a `descendant-or-self` axis: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

`//*[@id="codeRow"]/td[contains(., "Besnier")]`

XPath engine will convert `.`(current node) to `string`, then call function `contains()`.

The current node and all child nodes are searched for a text node fragment "Besnier", there is no need to use an axis to select all descendants and their text nodes.

Comment: This does not return both `td` and `strong` elements as the original XPath posted by @user3574960 did. For that you would need a union, e.g.

//*[@id="codeRow"]/(td/strong[contains(text(),"Besnier")] | td[contains(text(),"Besnier")]

Comment: In fact you could even simplify that to:

//*[@id="codeRow"]/(td | strong)[contains(text(),"Besnier")]